# Android SDK/Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have the latest SDK/Eclipse installed.
When I create an application and I run it under the emulator it runs fine.
When I re-run the application from the Eclipse IDE I get a warning message
that the process is already running and it will be brought to the front or something.
The solution I have is to close the emulator and then rerun the build.
Problem is that it takes a long time for the EMU to boot.
On my friends PC his system re runs the process without the error.
(It actually terminates the current process in the emulator and re runs it)
Does anyone know how I can solve this?
Thanks

```
[2011-07-07 22:05:28 - delme] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=x.y.z/.DelmeActivity }
[2011-07-07 22:05:28 - delme] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes, when Eclipse for some esoteric reason does not install the app but just tries to launch it. I don't know how to solve it as it happens randomly, but you could try to uninstall the app instead of relaunching the emulator.

Comment: I "solved" the issue by modifying a source file and recompiling the project. This really isnt a solution though as I would like to re run the application from the IDE without a compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quicker way to work around this problem:

1. Go to the home screen
2. Press the menu button
3. Choose Manage apps
4. Choose the All tab
5. Scroll down the list to find your app and tap it
6. Tap the Force stop button

Now try to run the app from Eclipse again and it should install and launch properly.